# Compute the boundary and interior of $\left \{ \left(t,\frac{1}{t}\right) : \frac{1}{4} <t <4\right \}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be given with $|\cdot |_\infty$.Compute the boundary and interior of $A=\left \{
>  \left(t,\frac{1}{t}\right) : \frac{1}{4} <t <4\right \}$

I suppose that the interior of $\left \{
 \left(t,\frac{1}{t}\right) : \frac{1}{4} <t <4\right \}$ is every point that lies on $f(t)=1/t$ with $1/4<t<4$.

I'm having trouble with the boundary - can anyone help?

Comment: No. Your computation of the interior is wrong. The actual interior is empty, because your set does not contain any open ball.

Comment: You even posted a question asking for tips on *how to prove that* $A$ *is not open*, previously. What would make you suppose that $A=\operatorname{int}A$, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interior is empty and the boundary (which is also the closure)  is $\{(t,\frac  1 t): \frac 1 4 \leq t \leq 4\}$.